# JavaScript - How can I run the javascript in all my html rows

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating invoice form, I have written a Java Script to calculate Tax and Discount price as the user the value, But it is just working in one row how can I enable it to work on all the rows

**Javascript to calculate discount and tax**

[image]

**Html form**

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see [ask] and [mcve]Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. This will help the Stack Overflow community by clarifying the problem.

Comment: Not the right way to ask the question. But, from the initial look at the image, it seems like you need unique "id" for each element in the row. Good luck.

Comment: For multiple forms use a `class` rather than `id` I would also change mysql for mysqli.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better option is to do this calculation in PHP itself but if you want to do this in Javascript the you can do something like this:

Try creating a JS function that takes in all the values and the id of output input field and make sure that the id of output field is distinct.

**JS Code**

```
function calculate(unit_price, quantity, discount, tax, output_id) {
    var subtotal = "do subtotal calc here";
    document.getElementById(output_id).value = subtotal;
}
```

**PHP/HTML Code**

```
<?php
    // mySQL Code goes here
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSAL_ASSOC))
?>
<div class="centered">
    <table border="1">
    <tr>
        <form id = "invoiceform" action="final.php" method="post">
        <td><input type="text" id="Sl_no" value="<?php echo $s; ?>"></td> <!-- DO NOT INCREASE $S HERE YET-->
        <td><input type="text" id="partno" value="<?php echo $p[$j]; ?>"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="description" value="<?php $row['Description']; ?>"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="unit_price" value="<?php echo $row['Unit_Price']; ?>"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="quantity" value=""></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="discount" value=""></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="tax" value=""></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="<?php echo 'subtotal_'.$s;?>" value=""></td>
        <script>
        calculate(<?php echo $row['Unit_Price']; ?>, <?php echo $row['Quantity']; ?>, <?php echo $row['Discount']; ?>, <?php echo $row['Tax']; ?>, <?php echo 'subtotal_'.$s; s++;?>);
        </script>
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**P.S.** Try making all the field ids distinct the way i made subtotal id distinct because a HTML page is supposed to have distinct IDs on elements

Comment: when i try to use the above code get an  error in subtotal stating : Uncaught Type error: Cannot set property 'value' of null

Comment: Just check if the key name comes out to be the same in both cases

Comment: i would still suggest  you to do this calculation on php end because user can easily  disable their JS on their browsers.

Comment: I am not sure how to do it in Php, I am new to php my friends suggested me to use Java, Can you give me suggestions so I will try to do it in php